# How to create a string that can be used as LHS and assigned a value to?

Tags: r, object

I feel stupid for asking such a simple question, but I am hitting my head in the wall.
Why does the paste0() create a string that cannot be not interpreted as name for an empty object ? Is there a different way of create the LHS that would be better?

As input I have a dataframe. As an output I want to have a new filtered dataframe.  This works fine as long as I manually type all the code.  However, I am trying to reduce repetition, and therefore I want to create a function that does the same thing, but then it is not working anymore.

```
library(magrittr)

df <- data.frame(
    var_a = round(runif(20), digits = 1),
    var_b = sample(letters, 20)
  )


### Find duplicates

df$duplicate_num <-  duplicated(df$var_a)
df$duplicate_txt <-  duplicated(df$var_b)
df                      # a check


### Create two lists of duplicates

list_of_duplicate_num <-
  df %>%
  filter(duplicate_num)
list_of_duplicate_num      # a check

list_of_duplicate_txt <-
  df %>%
  filter(duplicate_txt)
list_of_duplicate_txt    # a check '
```

So far everything works as expected.

I would like to simplify the code and make this to a function that takes the arguments "num" or "txt".  But I am having **problems with creating the LHS**.
The below should, in my mind, do the same as the code above.

```
 paste0("list_of_duplicate_", "num") <-
  df %>%
  filter(duplicate_num)
```

I do get an error message:

```
Error in paste0("list_of_duplicate_", "num") <- df %>% 
filter(duplicate_num) : 
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

My goal is to create a function with something like this:

```
make_list_of_duplicates <- function(criteria = "num") {
  paste0("list_of_duplicate_", criteria) <-
    df %>%
    filter(paste0("duplicate_", criteria))
  paste0("list_of_duplicate_", criteria)    # a check
}

### Create two lists of duplicates

make_list_of_duplicates("num")
make_list_of_duplicates("txt")

and then continue with some joins etc.
```

I have been looking to tidy evaluation, assignments, rlang::enexpr(), base::substitute(), get(), mget() and many other things, but after two day of reading and trial and error, I am convinced that there must be a an other direction to look at that I am not seeing.

I am running MS Open R 4.0.2.

I am grateful for any suggestions.

Sincerely,
Eero

Comment: (1) `paste0<-` doesn't exist, so you cannot have `paste0(.)` on the LHS of an assignment. (2) `dplyr::filter` needs a `logical` argument, not `character`, so `filter(paste0(.))` doesn't mean anything. (3) It sounds like you want non-standard evaluation for your function, I suggest you read http://adv-r.had.co.nz/. (4) It looks like your function intends to operate in side-effect, which is rarely the right thing to do and very easily goes wrong. At a minimum, it is not reproducible and can be very difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans !  1) I did not see that issue was simply with the LHS, so I reformulated the question from a Function problem to a LHS problem.  4) I planning to use functions inside functions.  My manually written code works, but for the sake of learning I am trying to make use of functions.  And it is quite possible that it is not a good idea. At least the saving does not justify the time used.

Comment: Look into `assign(paste0(...), obj)`. I discourage that function for most purposes, for many reasons, though based on your reply to (4), that's precisely where you want to go. (If you're explicitly studying/experimenting with side-effect in functions, then you're in the right direction. If not, then good luck, working reproducibly/reliably with functions that operate in side-effect can take more work, and troubleshooting is more difficult.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question, when I understood that it was a case of **indirection**. Because I was on a wrong track, I created lots of complications and made it more difficult than necessary. Thanks to @r2evans who pointed me in the right direction. I have in the mean time decided that I will use loops, instead of functions, but here is the working function:

```
## Example of using paste inside a function to refer to an object.
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

 
df <- data.frame(
    var_a = round(runif(20), digits = 1),
    var_b = sample(letters, 20)
  )


# Find duplicates

df$duplicate_num <-  duplicated(df$var_a)
df$duplicate_txt <-  duplicated(df$var_b)

# SEE https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#indirection-2

make_list_of_duplicates_f2 <- function(criteria = "num") {
  df %>%
    filter(.data[[paste0("duplicate_", {{criteria}})]])
}

# Create two lists of duplicates

list_of_duplicates_f2_num <-
    make_list_of_duplicates_f2("num")
list_of_duplicates_f2_txt <-
    make_list_of_duplicates_f2("txt")
```